# Como llevar un consecutivo guardando en una BD Oracle

Tags: oracle

Debo llevar un consecutivo que va incrementando a medida que se imprime un documento, antes lo llevaba en un documento de texto asi:

```
string conse1 = "consecutivo";
        string tempurl = "C:\\docequi\\" + conse1 + ".txt";
        LNumDoc.Text = File.ReadAllText(tempurl);
        int consecutivo = int.Parse(LNumDoc.Text);
        consecutivo = int.Parse(LNumDoc.Text) + 1;
        if (File.Exists(tempurl))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(tempurl, consecutivo.ToString());
        }
```

pero tengo problemas con los permisos de usuario para sobreescribir el consecutivo.

Entonces cree una tabla CCONSECUTIVO y el campo "consecutivo(de tipo INT)" en ORACLE para escribir y consultar el consecutivo, como podria hacer el INSERT en este caso y el procedimiento para incremente en 1 cada vez que abra o cierre la APP?

trabajo en VS con C#.

Comment: Si estás en Oracle no sería lo adecuado que uses una secuencia?

Comment: Como se implementaria?

Comment: Son autonuméricos en la base de datos y le pides el siguiente valor. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm

Comment: Ya veo pero soy novel en ORACLE no se como implementarla en mi APP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear secuencias en Oracle. De esa manera, tienes el incremental en la tabla cada vez. (no creo que necesites la tabla)

Crear una secuencia:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MI_SECUENCIA MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20;
```

Usar la secuencia:

```
SELECT MI_SECUENCIA.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;
```

Con eso, puedes traer el valor de la secuencia MI_SECUENCIA

http://ora.u440.com/ddl/create%20sequence.html

Si estas usando C#, no creo que debas hacer nada mas en el código que conectarte a oracle y consumir un procedimiento almacenado. Así, dejas que oracle haga las cosas.

Tu procedimiento en oracle quedaría algo como ésto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_secuencia(consec OUT NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
   consec:= MI_SECUENCIA.NEXTVAL;       
END;
```

no necesitas insertar en la tabla porque la secuencia ya se actualiza con el valor incremental.

El código de c# para lo que quieres es algo como esto:

```
oracommand.Parameters.Add("consec", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction =ParameterDirection.Output;

oracommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
var c = oracommand.Parameters["consec"].value;
```

Comment: El insert no es necesario, solo consumes el procedimiento almacenado desde c# y el te traería la secuencia

Comment: Si eso estaba pensando, voy a probar

Comment: `OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
OracleCommand comando;
OracleDataReader lector;
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = XXXX; User Id = XXXX; Password = XXXXX; Unicode = true;";
try
{
    oracommand.Parameters.Add("consec", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    oracommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    var c = oracommand.Parameters["consec"].value;
}
catch (Exception)
{
}`
hago esto pero me sale error en oracommand. y OracleDbType.

Comment: me sale error en oracommand. y OracleDbType.

Comment: te falta agregarle la conexion al command y tambien abrir la conexion: con.Open(); comando.Connection = con;

Comment: Si arregle eso lo que me falta es traer el valor al label
    `LNumDoc.Text = oracommand.Parameters["consec"].Value;`
no me esta funcionando

Comment: que error sale? hay que mirar la conversion de datos. si LNumDoc.Text recibe string, entonces toca hacer el cast:  LNumDoc.Text = (string)oracommand.Parameters["consec"].Value; Si no, entonces con String.Parse(...)

Comment: Exacto y si LNumDoc.Text recibe string pero String.Parse(...) no tiene definicion para .Parse

Comment: Listo arreglado ahora me sale este error **System.Data.OracleClient requiere la version 8.1.7 o posterior del software cliente Oracle**

Comment: Toca mirar que versión del conector de Oracle se está usando. Porque si la dll que usas en .net está para una versión distinta del SDK de Oracle, entonces va a generar errores.